# Count down timer in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want a count down timer to start ticking for two and half hours . I tried this using dispatcher timer

Please find the code below. But it is not updating the seconds properly. It is too fast. It ticks two seconds instead of 1 second at a time

```
    private void DrawBlackout()
    {
        TextBlock videoText = new TextBlock();
        dt = new DispatcherTimer();
        dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1); // 1 Seconds
        dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
        dt.Start();


    }

    void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something

       milliseconds = milliseconds - 1000;
       label.Text = getTimeText(milliseconds / 1000);
       elapsed += 1000;

        //Debug.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\n");
        if (milliseconds <= 1000)
            dt.Stop();
     }



    String getTimeText(long secVal)
    {

        String timeString = "";
        int seconds = (int)(secVal % 60);
        int minutes = (int)((secVal / 60) % 60);
        int hours = (int)((secVal / (60 * 60)) % 60);
        if (hours <= 9)
            timeString = "0" + Convert.ToString(hours) + " : ";
        else
            timeString = Convert.ToString(hours) + " : ";
        if (minutes <= 9)
            timeString = timeString + "0" + Convert.ToString(minutes) + " : ";
        else
            timeString = timeString + Convert.ToString(minutes) + " : ";
        if (seconds <= 9)
            timeString = timeString + "0" + Convert.ToString(seconds) + " ";
        else
            timeString = timeString + Convert.ToString(seconds) + " ";
        return timeString;
    }
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this on emulator or real device?

Comment: Rather than assuming each tick will be exactly 1000ms, you should save away the start time and at each tick see how much time has elapsed since the start. Then you could tick every 100ms or so and it should be pretty consistent looking.

Comment: What kind of application is someone going to be playing for 2 and half hours on a phone?

Answer (score -1):

```
void DisTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timeRefresh++;
            if (sec > 0)
            {
                sec--;
            }
            else if (sec == 0 && min > 0)
            {
                sec = 59;
                min--;
            }
            else if (sec == 0 && min == 0 && house > 0)
            {
                sec = 59;
                min = 59;
                house--;
            }
            txtHouse.Text = house.ToString();
            txtMin.Text = min.ToString();
            txtSec.Text = sec.ToString();

            if (sec == 0 && min == 0 && house == 0)
            {
                DisTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(DisTimer_Tick);
                getBuyer();
            }
            else if (timeRefresh == 60)
            {
                getBuyer();
                DisTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(DisTimer_Tick);
            }
        }
```

I hope to help you!

Thongaduka ( diadiem JSC)